# Continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphism-group

Goodmorning my queston is:
 Every continuous automoprhism of $\mathbb{C}_p$ is on the form

$$\sigma(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{\sigma}{(x_n})$$

where $x =\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n $ and  $\bar{\sigma}\in Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p/ \mathbb{Q}_p)$ and $x_n \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ ?
Beacause if $\sigma$ is on this form is surely an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}_p$ but the converse is true? I think that is not true but...

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear to me whether you are asking, as part of your question, whether every automorphism of $\Bbb C_p$ must be continuous.

I think that this is the nub, the crux, of the matter: if you start with *any* automorphism of $\Bbb C_p$, then it restricts to a continuous automorphism $\sigma_0$ of $\bar{\Bbb Q}_p$. Since $\sigma_0\in\text{Gal}(\bar{\Bbb Q}_p/\Bbb Q_p)$, it extends uniquely to the closure, i.e. to $\Bbb C_p$, and this extension must be the original $\sigma$, *if this $\sigma$ is known to be continuous*.

But: whether every automorphism of $\Bbb C_p$ is continuous (surely true?), this seems to me to be a more delicate question, which I’m not prepared to attack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i was asking in fact if we start with a continuous automorphism

Comment: Pick $a,b \in \Bbb{C}_p$ such that $\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}(a,b)/\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}$ is transcendental of degree $2$, the automorphism switching $a,b$ will extend (since $\Bbb{C}_p$ is algebraically closed) to a non-trivial $\sigma \in Aut(\Bbb{C}_p/\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p})$, this automorphism won't be continuous (as for $\sigma$ continuous $\sigma|_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}} = Id \implies \sigma = Id$ since $\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}_p$)

Comment: That makes it very clear, @reuns, and I should have seen it, as an argument valid equally for the complex number field, taking the base to be $\Bbb Q$ rather than $\Bbb Q_p$.